# FULLTEXT mysql search not working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If i search the word `hello` then i got no match, while i search the word `hella` then i got the match. The same thing happens with the word `Non`. I tested on MAMP on Mac and sqlfiddle.com with the same results. Do you have idea why?
Here is for test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40658/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` TEXT default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `product` (`name`) VALUES ("hello SANYO MC-1234");
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`) VALUES ("hella SANYO MC-1234");
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`) VALUES ("Non SONY");
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`) VALUES ("mac SONY");
```

Got 1 match:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+hella*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as `score` FROM `product` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+hella*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Got 0 match:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+hello*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as `score` FROM `product` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+hello*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use full text search, you need to learn about stop words and minimum word length.

The place to start is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

The short answer is that "hello" is a default stop word (as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)).  And, words shorter than 4 characters are ignored (such as "non").  The default minimum word length is documented as 4 [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).